# mime.lookup() is not a function in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use the "mime" package to get the Content-Type of a file for the first time. I have run the following code in different orders through the command prompt.

First I ran the mime commands first, then ran the "node" command to open node in command prompt, I then ran the node code(this gave me the rejection: "mime.look up not a function", the other time I ran the mime commands after opening node with the node command (this seemed to get me close to success). However I am getting "Unexpected token" pointing to the "mime@1.2.11" portion of the code. It points to the "@" symbol.

My NPM version is 6.13.4, node is 12.6.1.

Thank you.

```
    $ npm install mime
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
    mime@1.2.11 node_modules/mime

    var mime = require("mime"); 
    console.log(mime.lookup("/Users/evanredmond/Desktop/winter tent.rtf"));
```

Comment: please show the entire error that you're getting.

Comment: The second technique you tried is way off, and is distracting from your actual problem.  The first problem of `mime.lookup is not a function`, is the real problem, and is just because of the version of **mime** that you used.  It might even be worth changing the title. Would you consider changing the title?  (...to something about "mime.lookup is not a function")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Version 2 of mime is a breaking change to version 1, where

```
.lookup() renamed to .getType()
```

Either install mime version 1, or try using the updated function
Npm documentation on mime: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime

If you'd like to use .lookup(), then you should run:

```
npm uninstall mime
npm install mime@^1
```

Comment: Thanks, please accept my solution so that it gets moved to the top and can help others facing the same problem in the future.

Comment: At least with node v16 I still have the .lookup() method and had to downgrade my "mime" dependency.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Change the following where the `lookup` is defined -

from

```js
var charset = mime.lookup(type);
```

to

```js
var charset = mime.getType(type);
```

**Step 2**
Change the following where the `charsets.lookup` is defined -
from

```js
 var charset = mime.charsets.lookup(type);
```

to

```js
 var charset = mime.getType(type);
```